# Como puedo sacar la extension .html a la url de mi sitio web?

Tags: html, web, url

Quiero usar las url amigables, probé con el siguiente código en el `htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Así mismo, he probado varios códigos que encontré y no se pudo solucionar, mi pagina es pixelpotencia.com y esta hecha con HTML, CSS y JavaScript.

gracias de ante mano!

Answer (score 0):

Para las extensiones. Este código jamás me ha fallado.

```
# Quitar extensión de las URL
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
# END Quitar extensión de las URL
```

PD: Quito los **.php** y **.html**

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo podrías hacerlo:

1. Abre o crea un archivo llamado .htaccess en la raíz de tu sitio web
   si aún no existe.
2. Añade las siguientes líneas de código al archivo .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```